# React and Date() and useState() used together not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, codesandbox

The following code prints the time with the text "am" or "pm" behind the time string.  So the time string overlaps the am or pm string and can be seen behind it on the  z index.  In other words, if the format is [hh:mm:ss a] where a = am/pm, the a is show behind the hh:mm:ss and centered as well.  How can I fix this? I am using codesandbox here is the link below
https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-hook-practice-forked-t1zkyl?file=/src/components/App.jsx

```
function App() {

  const now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

  const [time, setTime] = useState(now);


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{time}</h1>
      <button>Get Time</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This unexpected behavior I'm sure that it's not from React i think there's something is missing you're not included it in your post i check the function and it's working without any problem

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud for taking the time to answer.  I should have mentioned that I am using code sand box.  Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-hook-practice-forked-t1zkyl?file=/src/components/App.jsx

Comment: Are you having issue with styling or what is the issue here?

Comment: The output of the above code shows the date such as 5:33:26 am with am behind the 33 rather than after the 26.  Looks like <h1>{time}<h1> is being rendered twice, once for the 5:33:26 and again for the am and displayed all at once in a browser.  I am sure it has something to do with the timing rather than styling as I have tried changing things in the .css file already.

Answer (score 0):

Please restart the server. Because this is working just fine.

[image]

Check in this link : https://playcode.io/1048731

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a styling issue. The font size for the body was to small to accommodate the font size for the heading. I just doubled the body font size in styles.css and it works now. Thank you innocent and Mahmoud Y3c so much! Always looking of people to network with and to collaborate with. Just getting started learing NodeJS, React, mongoDB so much appreciated!